# Fisher Z backtransformation with metafor package

Tags: correlation, metafor

I've used the Fisher Z transformation to obtain an averaged Pearson correlation coefficient between 19 subjects with the metafor package in R. To perform the back transformation I tried to use two different functions: transf.ztor(xi) and transf.ztor.int(xi, targs).I got the same results with both functions.
Did it happen to anyone or did I make any mistake?

Thank you for your time!

Everything on the script looks ok.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.